# Creating new Records on initialization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have searched through similar posts with similar titles, but can't figure out the answer. It is a newb question, apologies in advance.

I want to add records to my database on initialization, to continually check what videos I have in my local directory. Please note, this application is ONLY for local development, not for deployment.

What silly mistakes am I making here?

```
saved_videos_controller.rb

Dir.glob("#{ROOTPATH}/lib/videos/*.mp4").each do |item|
    size = File.size(item)  
    @extension = File.extname(item)
    name = File.basename(item)
    @name = name[0...name.index(@extension)]
    @rootpath = item[0..item.rindex('/')]

    SavedVideo.create(:name => @name,:extension => @extension) unless size==0 
end

def index
    @saved_videos = SavedVideo.all
end

saved_video.rb

class SavedVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :filename, :extension
    validates :filename, :extension, presence: true

    def self.name
    @name
    end

    def self.extension
     @extension
    end
end

schema.rb
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150207072508) do

  create_table "saved_videos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "filename"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "extension"
end
```

Comment: @onathan_What error or exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to move your code into config/initializers/. i.e.

config/initializers/videos.rb

```
Dir.glob("#{ROOTPATH}/lib/videos/*.mp4").each do |item|
    size = File.size(item)  
    @extension = File.extname(item)
    name = File.basename(item)
    @name = name[0...name.index(@extension)]
    @rootpath = item[0..item.rindex('/')]

    SavedVideo.create(:name => @name,:extension => @extension) unless size==0 
end
```

You could also create a rake take that you can call or schedule.